# Using Qt libraries on VS

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to build a C++ project on VS. The project was developed using NetBeans in a Linux machine and now I am using Visual Studio 2017 on Windows.

It wasn't developed using Qt Creatos so the libraries has been added manually with sentences like:

```
#include <QtCore>
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QObject>
#include <QStringList>
#include <QMap>
...
```

This is what I did so far:

- Downloaded the last Qt release
- Unpacked everything in C:\Qt
- In VS properties > VC++ Directories > Include directories - I added C:\Qt\Qt5.9.2\5.9.2\msvc2017_64\include and C:\Qt\Qt5.9.2\5.9.2\msvc2017_64\include\QtCore
- In VS properties > VC++ Directories > Library directories - I added C:\Qt\Qt5.9.2\5.9.2\msvc2017_64\lib

However, when I try to `#include <QtCore>` it seems like VS expects something more:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/txZrX.jpg

but it doesn't compile.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "QEvent" is undefined        c:\Qt\Qt5.9.2\5.9.2\msvc2017_64\include\QtCore\qabstractanimation.h 121 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "QEvent" is undefined    c:\Qt\Qt5.9.2\5.9.2\msvc2017_64\include\QtCore\qabstractstate.h 73  
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "QEvent" is undefined    c:\Qt\Qt5.9.2\5.9.2\msvc2017_64\include\QtCore\qabstractstate.h 74  
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "QEvent" is undefined    c:\Qt\Qt5.9.2\5.9.2\msvc2017_64\include\QtCore\qabstractstate.h 76  
Error (active)  E1455   member function declared with 'override' does not override a base class member      c:\Qt\Qt5.9.2\5.9.2\msvc2017_64\include\QtCore\qabstracttransition.h    105 
Error (active)  E1455   member function declared with 'override' does not override a base class member  c:\Qt\Qt5.9.2\5.9.2\msvc2017_64\include\QtCore\qanimationgroup.h    70  
Error (active)  E1455   member function declared with 'override' does not override a base class member  c:\Qt\Qt5.9.2\5.9.2\msvc2017_64\include\QtCore\qcoreapplication.h   190 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "qint8" is undefined c:\Qt\Qt5.9.2\5.9.2\msvc2017_64\include\QtCore\qdatastream.h    147 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "qint8" is undefined c:\Qt\Qt5.9.2\5.9.2\msvc2017_64\include\QtCore\qdatastream.h    163 
Error (active)  E0260   explicit type is missing ('int' assumed)    c:\Qt\Qt5.9.2\5.9.2\msvc2017_64\include\QtCore\qendian.h    236 
Error (active)  E0801   "qint8" is not a class or function template name in the current scope   c:\Qt\Qt5.9.2\5.9.2\msvc2017_64\include\QtCore\qendian.h    236 
Error (active)  E0065   expected a ';'  c:\Qt\Qt5.9.2\5.9.2\msvc2017_64\include\QtCore\qendian.h    236 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "qint8" is undefined c:\Qt\Qt5.9.2\5.9.2\msvc2017_64\include\QtCore\qendian.h    236 
Error (active)  E0020   identifier "QEvent" is undefined    c:\Qt\Qt5.9.2\5.9.2\msvc2017_64\include\QtCore\qeventloop.h 79  
Error (active)  E1455   member function declared with 'override' does not override a base class member
...
```

So, I guess I'm missing something. I am new with VS, so I would appreciate any help.

Thank you

Comment: _it doesn't compile._ - show the compiler messages

Comment: Just use online/offline installer instead of manual unpacking/building Qt. And use Qt addin for visual studio 2017

Comment: @scopchanov yeah sorry, edited.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov yeah, I did it that way, but the installer just unpacks all the components into given folder, isn't it?
I used the offline installer: qt-opensource-windows-x86-5.9.2.exe

Comment: @enekow no, it also patch Qt5Core.dll and do some other stuff. Once again: have you installed Qt addin?

Answer (score 2):

`QtCore` is both a directory and an include file:

```
Directory: <Qt_Install_Path>/include/QtCore
File:      <Qt_Install_Path>/include/QtCore/QtCore
```

Also you need to run the Qt `moc` on every header that contains the `Q_OBJECT` macro. The `moc` will generate extra C++ files, which you need to compile. It is fairly straightforward when using tools like `qmake` or `cmake`. For VS you might wan to use [Qt Visual Studio Add-in](https://www.qt.io/download-open-source/#section-10).

Comment: Thanks @Benjamin must be that. I installed the Qt VS Tools however, the only options I have are `Qt Designer`, `Qt Linguist` and `open Qt prj`. I already added my Qt version into Qt options, but I am not able to figure it out how to automatize running the moc. Thx!

Comment: @enekow it will create build rules for moc automatically, if you will create a Qt project in VS.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov so the workaround would be to start a new Qt project in VS and get my files back into it. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @enekow it is not a workaround. It is a way how it should be. But anyway, development of Qt addin is very slow, so I prefer to use CMake in my projects. It doesn't require qt addin and works natively with most IDEs.

Comment: @enekow Alternatively, if you do not have a need for the Visual Studio IDE, but only need the MSVC compiler, you can use the Visual C++ compiler command line directly, or with another IDE, and use the .pro file (or whatever you have) directly.

Comment: The thing is that I must to use VS... Apart from that, I do not have any .pro file. The only thing used for the project I am trying to import, were some libraries of QtCore.

Comment: @enekow Why would you need to use a particular IDE?

Comment: @BenjaminT companys policy I guess... :(